# ASP.Net How to access images from different applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 different project. One is supposed to upload images (admin) and the other is supposed to show them.

I was writing something like "/Contents/images/image path"... But wait! I will I upload the images from the application into that address?

Any help and suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two applications that will interact with the same files, it's probably better to have an ImageController with an action that allows you to upload/download the image rather than storing them directly as content.  That way both applications can reference the same file location or images stored in a database and manipulate them.  Your download action would simply use a FileContentResult to deliver the bytes from the file.  You can derive the content type from the file extension.

Example using a database.  Note that I assume that the database table contains the content type as determined at upload time.  You could also use a hybrid approach that stores the image metadata in a database and loads the actual file from a file store.

```
 public class ImageController : Controller
 {

      public ActionResult Get( int id )
      {
           var context = new MyDataContext();
           var image = context.Images.SingleOrDefault( i => i.ID == id );
           if (image != null)
           {
               return File( image.Content, image.ContentType );
           }
           // or you could return a placeholder image here if appropriate.
           throw new HttpException( 404, "The image does not exist" );
      }
 }
```

An alternative would be to incorporate your administrative interface in an area of the same application rather than in a separate project.  This way you could reuse the content/images directory if you wanted.  I find that when you have dynamic images the database or a hybrid approach works better from a programming perspective since it's more consistent with the rest of your data model.

Comment: So, using your suggestion, only one project would deal with getting and uploading images. The other project's forms would only reference the other project location (like http://www.myothermvc.tld/get-or-upload) in the action attribute to do whatever it has to do. Is this what you mean @tvanfosson?

Comment: @FabioMilheiro you could go either way.  If you don't have content restrictions, i.e., you allow public access to the images, it would be okay to put it all in one application and simply reference it.  If you want to apply access restrictions, i.e., you can't access the image unless logged in or in a particular role, have image controllers in both apps and simple reference the same file store or database.

Comment: It's all public. Thanks a log @tvanfosson! Always an amazing help!

Answer (score 1):

you could try like this..

Let's assume that all of your images are in Project A and you want to use the same images in Project B.

Open Project B with Visual Studio.  In the Solution Explorer, right click your Project Name and select "Add Existing Item...".

Browse to the physical location on disc where your images in Project A are stored and select the files that you want to import.

You'll then be able to access those images from project A in Project B.

Comment: You mean well, but the images I'm talking about are not static. Good suggestion though.